# IF exists ELSE re: values from csv

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server

I have a csv input to a PowerShell script that has two email fields; one that will always contain a value and one that sometimes will, and when the latter value exists, that's the one I want to use to set a value used to set a mailcontact field later in the script, for the variable `$WriteEmail`.

So I've got the following to read the CSV:

```
# Read contacts
ForEach ($contact in $contactfile) {

# Read attributes
$sourceEmail=$contact.Email
$sourceOutlookEmail=$contact.OutlookEmail
```

And I need it to basically do:

```
IF $sourceOutlookEmail IsNullOrWhitespace
THEN $WriteEmail=$sourceEmail
ELSE $WriteEmail=$sourceOutlookEmail
```

I just can't get the syntax correct, I've tried all kinds of stuff. I know it's relatively simple, I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the static .net `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($sourceOutlookEmail))
{
   $WriteEmail=$sourceEmail
}
else
{
   $WriteEmail=$sourceOutlookEmail
}
```

Comment: Oh, OK, duh, I'd seen that method in a few similar examples but kept thinking the [string] was a placeholder for a value I needed to input there, not that it was supposed to actually SAY "[string]"

Gonna try it out, thanks!

Comment: [Relevant MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/using-static-classes-and-methods) :-)